# This button that I styled with css won't style

Tags: html, css

I styled this button with CSS and the style doesn't seem to be applied to the button. Links to websites. http://randomstufffrommybrain.neocities.org/TheRandomPage.html

The HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=CSSFORTherandompage.css>
 </head>
<div id="Button5">
  <button><a href=Newsitetestcode/Newwebsitemainpage.html>New website</a> 
  </button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
     #Button5 {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Close the `<div>` with a `</div>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/evxw9q73/

Comment: Given that the jsFiddle by @user2181397 shows that it actually does work, you need to provide a proper question.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for information on how to do this.

Comment: Saw your website in your edit, and the button is in fact styled correctly.

Comment: I think that you should use double quote in value of attributes

Answer (score 1):

The style does not appear on button because you have added style on the `div#Button5` but not button.

Apply this change in css

```
button{
background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 16px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/evxw9q73/1/)

Comment: I want to keep all of the buttons separate because eventually I want to make each of them different with CSS.

Comment: You should change the selector to `#Button5 button {` if you want to style only the `id="Button5"` button.

Comment: I didn't have to do that with all other of the buttons, though.

Comment: What web browser are you using? When I view your site in both Firefox and Chrome, every button is styled in (almost) the same way. They all have the same problem.

Comment: I use chrome as my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `link` tag in the `head` section of your HTML file.

> Note: This element goes only in the head section, but it can appear any number of times.

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Answer (score 0):

- All `<link>` tags should go inside the `<head>`
- Make sure you have your external CSS in the same folder as your HTML, as indicated in your `link` tag. If it is in another folder, give the appropriate path.

For further debugging, you can employ some JS:

```
function sheetLoaded() {
  // Do something interesting; the sheet has been loaded
}

function sheetError() {
  alert("An error occurred loading the stylesheet!");
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" onload="sheetLoaded()" onerror="sheetError()">
```

Comment: Its in the head and it is in the same folder as the HTML. Also, If I need to, how do put in the Js. (Sorry, don't know Js yet)

Comment: JS goes inside a `<script>` tag ; usually in the <head>. 
Look at user2181397's answer. It may solve your issue.

Comment: I added the JS. Did, nothing,